Is $T^{(1,1)} E$ (instead of $T^{(1,2)}(E)$ ) the generalization of $T^{(1,2)} TM$ to generic vector bundles?
By the tensor characterization lemma  (see picture)  a (1,1)-tensor, ie and element of $T^{(1,2)} TM$ is equivalent to a trilinear map that take: Two inputs from $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ (two vector fields), and output a vector field from $\mathfrak{X}(M)$.
If I generalize this to  a generic vector bundle E instead of TM, it looks like I have to consider $T^{(1,1)} E$ ? I don't understand why not  $T^{(1,2)} E$ which looks the natural thing to do?
That is, I don't understand why, for a general vector bundle $E$, the space that refers to bilinear maps that take:

One input from $\mathfrak{X}(M)$, the space of vector fields on $M$,
One input from $\Gamma(E)$, the space of sections of $E$,
and output a section of $E$.

would be denoted $T^{(1,1)} E$ and not $T^{(1,2)} E$
This is all in the context of trying to generalize and prove the folllowing theorem (given for tangent bundles ) to the case of vector bundles


I can prove it for TM, but for E, I am not sure how to write it or use sections very well, I found out I had to consider $T^{(1,1)} E$, and don't see why. I would appreaciate if you could also prove it in this more general case

Tensor characterization lemma:

